# Download Dash to mp4 with exoplayer

Tags: java, android, mp4, exoplayer

I want to download a video that is in Dash format using exoplayer. The following code downloads the video for me but in multiple files.

```
import android.app.Notification
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.Log
import ar.com.flow.iot.R
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.database.StandaloneDatabaseProvider
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.Download
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.DownloadManager
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.DownloadService
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.scheduler.Scheduler
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DownloadNotificationHelper
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.SimpleCache
import java.io.File
import java.util.concurrent.Executor


class MyDownloadService : DownloadService(
    FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_ID,
    1000,
    DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
    R.string.exo_download_notification_channel_name,
    0
) {

    override fun getDownloadManager(): DownloadManager {

        Log.w("TAGGG_DOWNLOAD", "getDownloadManager")

        val databaseProvider = StandaloneDatabaseProvider(this)

        val downloadsDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

        val cacheDirectory = File(downloadsDirectory, "media_cache")

        val cacheEvictionPolicy = LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(50 * 1024 * 1024) // 50 MB

        val downloadCache = SimpleCache(
            cacheDirectory,
            cacheEvictionPolicy,
            databaseProvider
        )

        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()

        val downloadExecutor = Executor { obj: Runnable -> obj.run() }

        val downloadManager = DownloadManager(
            this,
            databaseProvider,
            downloadCache,
            dataSourceFactory,
            downloadExecutor
        )

        // Optionally, setters can be called to configure the download manager.
        //downloadManager.requirements = requirements;
        downloadManager.maxParallelDownloads = 3;

        return downloadManager

    }

    override fun getScheduler(): Scheduler? {
        Log.e("TAGGG_DOWNLOAD", "Falta implementar getScheduler ")
        return null
    }

    override fun getForegroundNotification(
        downloads: MutableList<Download>,
        notMetRequirements: Int
    ): Notification {
        Log.w("TAGGG_DOWNLOAD", "getForegroundNotification $downloads $notMetRequirements ")

        return DownloadNotificationHelper(this, DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID).buildProgressNotification(
            this,
            R.drawable.ic_icon_help,
            null,
            null,
            downloads,
            notMetRequirements
        )

    }

    companion object {

        private const val FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1

        const val DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "download channel id"

    }
}

private fun downloadVideo(uri:Uri) {
    val downloadRequest = DownloadRequest.Builder(id, uri).build()

    DownloadService.sendAddDownload(
        this,
        MyDownloadService::class.java,
        downloadRequest,
        false
    )
}
```

How should the code be so that the saved file has mp4 format?

Thank you so much

I think the problem is due to "dataSourceFactory", I tried some variants, like DefaultDataSourceFactory but I couldn't make ir work.

Answer (score 0):

DASH files is temporary files created during a MPEG-DASH video stream (Youtube, Crunchyroll etc...) and I believe unless the owner gives you MP4 direct stream, there is no way you can get MP4 unless you can get the whole segments of the video and then convert it to MP4 later?

Comment: How can I join the segments and create the mp4?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

ExoPLayer includes documentation on downloading adaptive streams (DASH. HLS etc) using a download helper. By default it should download the highest quality track available, rather than all the tracks.

Documentation is available here: https://exoplayer.dev/downloading-media.html#downloading-and-playing-adaptive-streams

This includes the example below, shared here in case the link changes:

```js
DownloadHelper downloadHelper =
    DownloadHelper.forMediaItem(
        context,
        MediaItem.fromUri(contentUri),
        new DefaultRenderersFactory(context),
        dataSourceFactory);
downloadHelper.prepare(myCallback);
```